# Submitting a Form with JSON Data in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

In short, we have specific requirements.  That is to place certain data into form elements and then submit the form.  The reason we're doing this is so a new window opens to return an excel spreadsheet, but we need to give the parameters to the form request.

Basically, my data points (clickPoints variable in javascript) isn't being passed to the action method on the server-side, but it is in the form request.

As follows:

```
$("#excel").click(function() {
    $("#Points").val(getExcelDataPoints(clickPoints));
    $("#GeomType").val("LINESTRING");
    $("#StartDate").val($("#start-date").val());
    $("#EndDate").val($("#end-date").val());
    $("#ExcelExport").submit(); // this is the form which I want to submit
});
```

All of the other parameters work fine, except for the points.  Here's the definition of the getExcelDataPoints

```
function getExcelDataPoints(points)
{
    var data = "{'Points': [";

     for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
         data += "{'Da': '" + points[i].lat() + "', 'Ea': '" + points[i].lng() + "'},"; 
     }

     data = data.substr(0, data.length - 1);
     data += "]}";

     return data;
}
```

You may be wondering why I'm constructing it manually.  There are reasons.  The thing is, this *definitely* works when doing an `$.ajax` request using jquery, so I know the format is absolutely fine.  But, when doing the first code listing as above, it doesn't work.

Here's the action definition on the server;

```
[HttpPost]
public IList<AISExcelPosition> ExcelExport(LatLng[] Points, GeomType GeomType, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)
{
     var poo = Request.Form["Points"];
        // Magical.... UNICORNS!
        /* 
             `\
               \\,
                \\\,^,.,,.
                ,;7~((\))`;;,,
                ,(@') ;)`))\;;',
                 )  . ),((  ))\;,
                /;`,,/7),)) )) )\,,      ,,,... ,
               (& )`   (,((,((;( ))\,_,,;'`    `\\,
                `"    ` ), ))),/( (            `)\,
                       '1/';/;  `               ))),
                        (, (     /         )    ((/,
                       / \                /     ((('
                      ( 6--\%  ,>     ,,,(     /'))\'
                       \,\,/ ,/`----~`\   \    >,))))'
                         \/ /          `--7>' /((((('
                         (,9             // /'('((\\\,
                          \ \,,         (/,/   '\`\\'\
                           `\_)1        (_)Kk    `\`\\`\
                             `\|         \Z          `\
                               `          "            `

         */
```

Yes.  I have a pet unicorn in my code.

You'll see the `var poo = Request.Form["Points"];` bit which we shoved in there which proved to us (and after observing the form data in the underlying POST request) that the data is indeed there, all nicely formatted.

Here's the actual JSON data:

```
"{'Points': [{'Da': '49.45995313552066', 'Ea': '-2.5134216308593977'},{'Da': '49.45894893804116', 'Ea': '-2.5134216308593977'}]}"
```

Any clues on what I should be doing?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? I can't really grasp what you are asking here / where your problem is.

Comment: +1 for keeping pet unicorn ..

Comment: @Marcel Jackwerth: the Points variable on the server-side never has a value, it's always null.

Comment: Could you post your html-form along?

Comment: Can you please post a Cyclops?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that your points are being delivered to the server as a string value, and not being interpreted as JSON.

`$.ajax` works because the string returned from `getExcelDataPoints(points)` is a JSON object with a property called `Points`, this matches up directly to your action parameter.  It's kind of in this format: `{ ... }`.  When you place that object inside an input element, it changes to be more like this format: `"{ ... }"`, which is a string.

Another far less important problem with this setup is that `getExcelDataPoints(points)` is generating the property name `Points` and then you take that and put it in your field which is also named `Points`, giving you an extra wrapper so the values look more like `Points.Points[]` instead of just `Points[]`.

To test if you can send JSON data in a regular form submit, I set up a quick MVC3 project and altered the Home/Index view to have the following code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("About", "Home"))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="Points" value="[{'Da': '49.45995313552066', 'Ea': '-2.5134216308593977'},{'Da': '49.45894893804116', 'Ea': '-2.5134216308593977'}]" />
    <input type="submit" />
}

<a id="jason">Run The Query!</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#jason').click(function (event) {
        $.post('@Url.Action("About")', {'Points': [{'Da': '49.45995313552066', 'Ea': '-2.5134216308593977'},{'Da': '49.45894893804116', 'Ea': '-2.5134216308593977'}]}, function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

The Home/About action was changed as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult About(LatLng[] Points)
{
    var poo = Request.Form["Points"];

    return Json("hello");
}
```

And this confirmed it was coming across as a string.  You can submit a list to an action using various methods [shown here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx), so I figured I'd hack up some quick js to format your JSON into form elements which would work for what you are doing.  It's not pretty, but if you are forced to use form submit, it will work (or as [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80572/kevin-montrose) puts it, I'll show you how to shoot yourself in the foot, but you have to make the decision to do it):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("About", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "point-maker" }))
{
    <input type="submit" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var points = [{ 'Da': '49.45995313552066', 'Ea': '-2.5134216308593977' }, { 'Da': '49.45894893804116', 'Ea': '-2.5134216308593977'}];
        var form = $('.point-maker');
        for (var index in points) {
            var point = points[index];
            form.append(CraftHiddenPoint(index, point.Da, point.Ea));
        }
    });
    function CraftHiddenPoint(index, da, ea) {
        return $('<input type="hidden" name="Points[' + index + '].Da" value="' + da + '" /><input type="hidden" name="Points[' + index + '].Ea" value="' + ea + '" />');
    }
</script>
```